# For how long does the force in $τ=rF\sinθ$ exert on the object that it sets into rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

When calculating torque using formulas such as $τ=rF\sinθ$, is the force $F$ exerted on the object for an extended period of time (i.e. the force is still exerted on the object even when the object is at a different position on its path than its starting position) or does the force leave the object immediately after it sets the object into rotation? How can we tell which is the case from examining the formula $τ=rF\sinθ$? And what is this formula lacking so that it can't be the other case?

Comment: **You** need to tell **us** where **you** think the formula applies. We're NOT mind readers.

Comment: @Gert I don't see how the OP is expecting anyone to be a mind reader.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Because he pulls that formula completely out of context.

Comment: @Gert An exercise problem got me into thinking about the question that I asked here. I was afraid that posting the problem itself will make my question a homework question so it'll be closed down.......

Comment: @Gert The problem that inspired my question is the follows if you are interested: A particle is located at coordinates
What is the magnitude of the torque about the origin when the
particle is acted upon by a force of magnitude 5.0 N in the
positive x direction

Comment: @Cheryl Just one small diagram would have made it clear why the torque was $\tau rF\sin\theta$, Never mind.

Comment: A short lived force is called an impulse, and it is measured not by force magnitude, but by the area under the curve $J = \int F \,{\rm d}t$. An impulse has units of momentum and it describes an imparting of momentum to the body through the line of action of the force.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\boldsymbol\tau=\mathbf r\times \mathbf F$ is just the definition of torque. Its behavior is completely dependent on $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf F$. So, if you want to know torque as a function of time, look at those values as a function of time: $\boldsymbol\tau (t)=\mathbf r(t)\times \mathbf F(t)$. The definition applies in any situation where a force is being applied.

Comment: Just to make sure, so the vanilla τ=r×F just gives us the torque an *instantaneous* force with the magnitude F will cause to an object that's $r$ unit away from the rotational axis?

Comment: @Cheryl I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Is it that the longer we apply a force on an object, the more torque it will have/the more torque will be produced by the force? If so, then shouldn't the amount of time for which we apply our force on that object be accounted for when we calculating torque using formulas such as τ=rFsinθ?

Comment: @Cheryl Torque doesn't accumulate. It's just a property of the force. Just like how forces have magnitude and direction, they also have a torque about some reference point.

Comment: Thank you! Just to make sure about how torque appears in real life scenarios. So torque is basically the rotation an object gets after we **flick** it with a certain force, as opposed to us continuously push the object with that same force as the object travels in its circular path?

Comment: @Cheryl No, torque is not rotation. It is just a property of a force. Just like how forces have magnitude and direction, forces also have a torque about some reference point. It is true of any force, not just "flicks". There doesn't need to be any rotation for a force to have a torque, just like how there doesn't need to be motion for a force to have a magnitude and direction.